# Accessing a variable inside a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am in a react app and making a call using axios:

```
   import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
      getData : function(callback){

        var instance = axios.create({
          baseURL: '//abc/json',
          withCredentials: false
        });

        instance.get('')
            .then((response) => {              
                  callback(response.data.abc);                
              }, (error) => {
                  callback(error)
              });
         }
    }
```

In another file, I am doing the following:

```
import file from './file';


//class definition...

    componentDidMount(){

        var obj = {}
        var res = file.getData(function(abc){
            obj['abc'] = abc;
        });

        console.log('obj-abc ', obj.abc); //returns undefined
      }
```

As shown above, I keep getting undefined. I basically, want the variable to  be available globally. I looked at other suggestions regarding callbacks on this site but none of them could help me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: GetData method is async and javascript not. Your file.getData will return results later in time when console already will be printed. Just add  console.log('obj-abc ', obj.abc);  inside file.getData and you will see that all OK.

Comment: if you are printing **console.log('obj-abc ', obj.abc);** then its perfectly work fine but in your case while it printing the value of obj.abc the value to not available because getData() is async method and componentDidMount() method not wait for complete getData() method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put

```
componentDidMount(){

var obj = {}
var res = file.getData(function(abc){
    obj['abc'] = abc;
    console.log('obj-abc ', obj.abc);
});
```

Since the getData method is asynchronous, it will not necessarily be executed sequentially in the javascript code. This variable is already global but if you want to make sure you can use it right after it, put some kind of completion condition before continuing code execution.

Comment: what type of completion condition are you suggesting? I wanted the value to be available globally.

Comment: Something like after console.log, you could put 
var isGetDataDone = True;

and in the other function you want to execute after this one simply put

if (isGetDataDone){

}

Answer (score -1):

Just to be clear on JS here.
Look at code

```
setTimeout(met1, 0);
console.log("11");    
setTimeout(met2, 0);
console.log("22");
```

Out put will be like this

```
11
22
met1 output
met2 output
```

So always keep in mind that async code will be executed in future and not in this moment. Will save you a lot of time in debugging. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is not what the OP has asked. Consider commenting on the question and not post it as an answer

Comment: I give him answer in comment. This is just for him to understand why this problem appear.